# Python, сортировка обьектов по атрибуту date

Tags: python, сортировка, дата, datetime

Имеется массив с обьектами классов, каждый обьект имеет атрибут - date,  каким образом отсортировать обьекты в массиве по дате, дата в формате dd-mm-yyyy, 
насколько я понимаю такой метод не сработает ,  так как знак ">" не может сравнивать даты , тогда может нужно создать метод **gt**? , в общем в растерянности.

```
class Event:

    events = []

    def __init__(self, date):

        self.date = date
        self.add_event(self)

    @classmethod
    def add_event(cls, event):

        cls.events.append(event)
        cls.sort_events()


    @classmethod
     def sort_events(cls):

        is_sorted = False

        while not is_sorted and len(cls.events) > 1:

            for i in range(len(cls.events) - 1):
                if cls.events[i].date > cls.events[i+1].date:
                    cls.events[i].date, cls.events[i+1].date = cls.events[i+1].date, cls.events[i].date
            is_sorted = True
```

Comment: Нужно приводить код, который любой желающий может запустить и проверить его работу, а ваш таким не является.

Comment: В ответ добавил пример такого кода ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Event:
    events = []

    def __init__(self, date):
        self.date = date
        self.add_event(self)

    @classmethod
    def add_event(cls, event):
        cls.events.append(event)
        cls.sort_events()

    @classmethod
    def sort_events(cls):
        cls.events.sort(key=lambda event: event.date)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Event({})>'.format(self.date.date())


e = Event(datetime(1999, 1, 1))
e = Event(datetime(2000, 1, 1))
e = Event(datetime(1999, 1, 1))
e = Event(datetime(1960, 1, 1))

print(e.events)
print(Event.events)
```

Консоль:

```
[<Event(1960-01-01)>, <Event(1999-01-01)>, <Event(1999-01-01)>, <Event(2000-01-01)>]
[<Event(1960-01-01)>, <Event(1999-01-01)>, <Event(1999-01-01)>, <Event(2000-01-01)>]
```